# Sending email using sendgird

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I am trying to send email using sendgrid. The email is delivered, but when i check it, the content is missing.

I followed the instruction provided by sendgrid.

-config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

-edit config/environment.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
:port => '25',
:domain => "halo.dev",
:authentication => :plain,
:user_name => "account",
:password => "password"
}
```

The email can be successfully delievered. However,it only shows

```
from    halo@halo.net via sendgrid.me 
to  user@user.com
date    Wed, Nov 2, 2011 at 5:23 PM
mailed-by   sendgrid.me
signed-by   sendgrid.me
```

No content html is shown

What I have tried:

1. deliever the email as file    (i.e config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :file)   It works fine. I got the file in local
2. deliever the email using the program itself   (i.e. config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail) It works fine too. When I check the email, everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on the Email Template App inside of your Sendgrid Account.